# Selecting row from array using session functions

Tags: php, arrays, function, session, counter

I'm trying to make a store page but am stuck at adding a product to the cart. I would like to do this through sessions using an array. Right now the function will add 1 of each row, while i just want it to add 1 for the row the button is in. Below is my code.

```
<?php

//Initialization
session_start();

include ("store_functions.php");

//Variables
$var = "";

if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
$var = "?sort=".$_GET['sort'];
}

//Table data
$products = array();
        $products[] = array("Product" => "Payday2", "System" => "PC",    "Price" => 29.99);
        $products[] = array("Product" => "Metal Gear Solid 5", "System" => "PS4", "Price" => 49.99);
        $products[] = array("Product" => "The Last of Us", "System" => "PS3", "Price" => 34.99);
        $products[] = array("Product" => "Forza 5", "System" => "XBOX ONE", "Price" => 59.99);
        $products[] = array("Product" => "Gran Turismo 6", "System" => "PS3", "Price" => 59.99);            

//Sorting table function
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
switch ($_GET['sort']) {
    case "prod": 
        $func = "sort_product";
    break;
    case "sys":
        $func = "sort_system";
    break;
    case "prc":
        $func = "sort_price";
    break;
    default:
        $func = "sort_product";
    break;
}
usort ($products, $func);
}

?>
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Gamestore Zero
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border='1'>
        <th>
            <a href='?sort=prod'>Product</a>
        </th>
        <th>
            <a href='?sort=sys'>Compatibility</a>
        </th>
        <th>
            <a href='?sort=prc'>Price</a>
        </th>
        <th>
            Add to cart
        </th>
        <tbody>
            <?php echo listing_array($products, $var);?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
        <p>
            Shopping cart
        </p>
        <p>
            <?php $func = add_product(); var_dump($func);?>
        </p>
        <p>
            Grand Total: $
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?php

//Array listing (function)
function listing_array ($products, $var){
$html = "";
foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
    $html.= "<tr><td>".$value["Product"]."</td><td>".$value["System"]."   </td><td>".$value["Price"]."</td><td><form action='store_session.php".$var."' method='POST'>
    <input type='submit' name='atc' value='Add'/><iput type='hidden' name='session_var' value='1'/></form></td></tr>";
}
return $html;
}   

//Sorting functionality (per array $Product)
function sort_product ($a, $b) {
if ($a["Product"]==$b["Product"]) {
    return 0;
}
if ($a["Product"]<$b["Product"]) {
    return -1;
}
return 1;
}

//Sorting functionality (per array $System)
function sort_system ($a, $b) {
if ($a["System"]==$b["System"]) {
    return 0;
}
if ($a["System"]<$b["System"]) {
    return -1;
}
return 1;
}

//sort functionality (per array $Price)
function sort_price ($a, $b) {
if ($a["Price"]==$b["Price"]) {
    return 0;
}
if ($a["Price"]<$b["Price"]) {
    return -1;
}
return 1;
}

//Add new item to cart(function)
function add_product () {
if (isset($_SESSION['session_var'])) {
    $_SESSION['session_var']++;
}
else {
    $_SESSION['session_var'] = "0";
}
return $_SESSION['session_var'];
}   


?>
```

Comment: If you have tables products in your database just use array_push function insert product ID in a session variable that is an array. Don't save everything in sessions.

Comment: I'm just starting with php, don't know the push function but thanks for the quick reply. I'll do some research on it.

Comment: @ameer: `array_push` adds overhead, because it's a function call. Instead of a function, use the language construct `$anArray[] = 'push this value';`.